# Unable to find explicit activity class with Navigation Drawer

Tags: android, android-activity, navigation-drawer, appcompatactivity

I've created project choosing Navigation Drawer Activity. And created a Contact class such as this:

```
public class ContactForm extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener { code here }
```

And from other Activity such as above but with this name:

```
public class SearchCar extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener { code here }
```

There are very similar but with different menù navigation drawer.
How can i call an activity that extends AppCompatActivity and implments NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener?

I've use simply in SearchCar form:

```
 Intent ContactForm = new Intent(this, ContactForm.class);
        startActivity(ContactForm);
```

But it didn't work.

Help me please.